# How do I do symmetric encryption with the python gnupg module vers. 1.2.5?

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg

I'm trying to do symmetric encryption with python and gnupg.

This code snippet works on my windows vista machine, on which the python gnupg module is version 0.3.2:

```
import gnupg
gpg = gnupg.GPG()
data = 'the quick brown fow jumps over the laxy dog.'
passphrase='12345'
crypt = gpg.encrypt(data, recipients=None,
                     symmetric='AES256',
                     passphrase=passphrase,
                     armor=False)
```

When I try to run it on my linux machine with the version 1.2.5 python gnupg module I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnupg/gnupg.py", line 961, in encrypt
    result = self._encrypt(stream, recipients, **kwargs)
TypeError: _encrypt() got multiple values for keyword argument 'recipients'
```

I have done a number of searches and can't find anything on this.

Answer (score 9):

This is an old ask, but I came upon this in a Google search and was unhappy with the provided answers. I found the real answer in python-gnupg's GitHub issues:

`gpg.encrypt(data, symmetric='AES256', passphrase=passphrase, armor=False, encrypt=False)`

So, drop the `recipients=None` and add an `encrypt=False`. Your crypt.data will then contain the encrypted data. Unintuitive, but it works.

(src: https://github.com/isislovecruft/python-gnupg/issues/110)

Comment: Encrypt seems to work, any idea as to how to decrypt?  gpg.decrypt(crypt.data, passphrase=passphrase) doesn't seem to work ...

Comment: gpg.encrypt(data, recipients=None, symmetric='AES256', passphrase=passphrase, armor=False) works on the last version

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just broken (correct me if I'm wrong). It appears to be fixed in `gnupg 0.3.6-1` for Python 3.x. You're probably better off using that or trying a workaround, such as one similar to what I'm about to describe.

This workaround uses the command-line `gpg` in Python instead of the `gnupg` module. You could do a similar workaround with `gpg.encrypt_file`, of course (which wouldn't have the temporarily stored passphrase I talk about in the next paragraph; that would most likely be a better choice).

If you're concerned about the passphrase showing up in the task manager, I took care of that by putting the password in a temporary file and using cat to pipe it into `gpg`. However, you *might* have to worry about malware snatching the password from the temporary file, if it can do it in time.

Note that this code is in Python 3.x, since that's what I use the most (to recreate it in 2.x you'll have to learn how temporary files work in it, and maybe a few other things).

```
import subprocess, tempfile, os, shutil

def gpg_encrypt(data, passphrase, alg="AES256", hash="SHA512", compress_alg="BZIP2", compress_lvl="9", iterations="1000000"):
    #This is for symmetric encryption.
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as directory:
        filepath=os.path.join(directory, "tmp")
        with open(filepath, "w") as FILE:
            FILE.write(data)
        iterations=str(iterations)
        compress_level="--compress-level "+compress_lvl
        if compress_alg.upper()=="BZIP2":
            compress_level="--bzip2-compress-level "+compress_lvl
        tmp_filename="tmp"
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as DIR:
            tmpfilepath=os.path.join(DIR, tmp_filename)
            with open(tmpfilepath, "w") as FILE:
                FILE.write(passphrase)
            subprocess.Popen("cat "+tmpfilepath+"|gpg --batch --yes --passphrase-fd 0 --force-mdc --s2k-mode 3 --s2k-count "+iterations+" --s2k-cipher-algo "+alg+" --s2k-digest-algo "+hash+" --compress-algo='"+compress_alg+"' --compress-level "+compress_lvl+" -ac '"+filepath+"'", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
        result=None
        with open(filepath+".asc", "r") as FILE:
            result=FILE.read()
        return result

def gpg_decrypt(data, passphrase):
    #This is for decryption.
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as directory:
        filepath=os.path.join(directory, "tmp")
        with open(filepath, "w") as FILE:
            FILE.write(data)
        decrypted=None
        tmp_filename="tmp"
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as DIR:
            tmpfilepath=os.path.join(DIR, tmp_filename)
            with open(tmpfilepath, "w") as FILE:
                FILE.write(passphrase)
            decrypted=subprocess.Popen("cat "+tmpfilepath+"|gpg --batch --yes --passphrase-fd 0 --output='"+filepath+".gpg"+"' '"+filepath+"'", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        result=None
        decrypted=not "decryption failed:" in str(decrypted)
        if decrypted==True:
            with open(filepath+".gpg", "r") as FILE:
                result=FILE.read()
    return decrypted, result #If it worked, return True. If not, return False. (And, return the decrypted data.)

test=gpg_encrypt(data="This is a test!", passphrase="enter")
print("Here is the encrypted message:\n"+test)
decrypted, data=gpg_decrypt(data=test, passphrase="enter")
if decrypted:
    print("Here is the decrypted message:\n"+data)
else:
    print("Incorrect passphrase to decrypt the message.")
```

Here's the code for encrypting/decrypting symmetrically encrypted files (just for good measure):

```
import subprocess, tempfile, os, shutil

def gpg_encrypt_file(filepath, passphrase, output=None, alg="AES256", hash="SHA512", compress_alg="BZIP2", compress_lvl="9", iterations="1000000"):
    #This is for symmetric encryption.
    filepath=filepath.replace("'", "'\\''") #This makes it so you can have apostrophes within single quotes.
    iterations=str(iterations)
    compress_level="--compress-level "+compress_lvl
    if compress_alg.upper()=="BZIP2":
        compress_level="--bzip2-compress-level "+compress_lvl
    result=None
    tmp_filename="tmp"
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as DIR:
        tmpfilepath=os.path.join(DIR, tmp_filename)
        with open(tmpfilepath, "w") as FILE:
            FILE.write(passphrase)
        if output:
            if output[0]!=os.sep and filepath[0]==os.sep:
                output=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filepath), output)
            result=subprocess.Popen("cat "+tmpfilepath+"|gpg --batch --yes --passphrase-fd 0 --force-mdc --s2k-mode 3 --s2k-count "+iterations+" --s2k-cipher-algo "+alg+" --s2k-digest-algo "+hash+" --compress-algo='"+compress_alg+"' "+compress_level+" --output='"+output+"' -ac '"+filepath+"'", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
        else:
            result=subprocess.Popen("cat "+tmpfilepath+"|gpg --batch --yes --passphrase-fd 0 --force-mdc --s2k-mode 3 --s2k-count "+iterations+" --s2k-cipher-algo "+alg+" --s2k-digest-algo "+hash+" --compress-algo='"+compress_alg+"' --compress-level "+compress_lvl+" -ac '"+filepath+"'", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
    return result.strip()

def gpg_decrypt_file(filepath, passphrase, output=None):
    #This is for decryption.
    filepath=filepath.replace("'", "'\\''")
    result=None
    tmp_filename="tmp"
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as DIR:
        tmpfilepath=os.path.join(DIR, tmp_filename)
        with open(tmpfilepath, "w") as FILE:
            FILE.write(passphrase)
        if output:
            if output[0]!=os.sep and filepath[0]==os.sep:
                output=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filepath), output)
            result=subprocess.Popen("cat "+tmpfilepath+"|gpg --batch --yes --passphrase-fd 0 --output='"+output+"' '"+filepath+"'", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        else:
            result=subprocess.Popen("cat "+tmpfilepath+"|gpg --batch --yes --passphrase-fd 0 '"+filepath+"'", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    return not "decryption failed:" in str(result) #If it worked, return True. If not, return False.

gpg_encrypt_file(filepath="test.txt", passphrase="myPassphrase", output="test.asc")
if gpg_decrypt_file(filepath="test.asc", passphrase="myPassphrase", output="output.txt"):
    print("Successfully decrypted!")
else:
    print("Incorrect passphrase.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The ["standard" `python-gnupg` module's](https://pypi.org/project/python-gnupg/) (instead of [pretty-bad-protocol's module](https://github.com/isislovecruft/python-gnupg)) symmetric-`encrypt()` call makes much more sense to me:

`encrypted_data = gpg.encrypt(data=msg, symmetric=True, passphrase='1234', recipients=None)`

Details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72355824/605356

Answer (score 0):

Double-check [the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/#encryption), the argument isn't `recipient`, is is `recipients` (note the plural)

Docs (emphasis mine):

> symmetric (defaults to False) If specified, symmetric encryption is
>   used. In this case, specify **recipients** as None. If True is specified,
>   then the default cipher algorithm (CAST5) is used. Starting with
>   version 0.3.5, you can also specify the cipher-algorithm to use (for
>   example, 'AES256'). Check your gpg command line help to see what
>   symmetric cipher algorithms are supported. Note that the default
>   (CAST5) may not be the best available.

Comment: Using `gpg.encrypt(data, recipients=None, symmetric='AES256', passphrase=passphrase, armor=False)` I get `TypeError: _encrypt() got multiple values for keyword argument 'recipients'`

Comment: It is `recipients` in my full code, but somehow the s got lost when I pulled out the code snippet to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with python-gnupg 0.3.5 and above (adjust as necessary):

```
import gnupg

gpg_home = "~/.gnupg"
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=gpg_home)

data = raw_input("Enter full path of file to encrypt: ")
phrase = raw_input("Enter the passphrase to decrypt the file: ")
cipher = raw_input("Enter symmetric encryption algorithm to use: ")
savefile = data+".asc"

afile = open(data, "rb")
encrypted_ascii_data = gpg.encrypt_file(afile, None, passphrase=phrase, symmetric=cipher.upper(), output=savefile)
afile.close()
```

Not sure about versions prior to 0.3.5.

The "None" for recipients does not (with current versions of the module) require "recipients=None" when the gpg.encrypt_file() is called.

Comment: I'm not using `gpg.encrypt_file`. I'm using `gpg.encrypt`, because my data is coming from python code as a string, not from a file. Would it be better to pass it to String.IO and use `gpg.encrypt_file`?

Comment: Using 'gpg.encrypt(data, None, symmetric='AES256', passphrase=passphrase, armor=False)' I get `ValueError: Unknown status message: u'NO_RECP'`

Answer (score 0):

```
        gpg = gnupg.GPG()
        data = 'the quick brown fow jumps over the laxy dog.'
        passphrase='12345'
        crypt = gpg.encrypt(
            data,
            recipients=None,
            symmetric='AES256',
            passphrase=passphrase,
            armor=False,
        )
        print(crypt.data)

        clear = gpg.decrypt(
            crypt.data,
            passphrase=passphrase,
        )

        print(clear)
```

As of July 28, 2022, The above works just fine for me.
Python 3.9.2 --
python-gnupg    0.4.9