# How to Python gnupg (GPG) encrypt with recipient's email address rather than their fingerprint?

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg, keyserver, python-gnupgp

How to Python-gnupg (GnuPG / GPG / OpenPGP) encrypt with recipient's email address rather than their fingerprint?

[This example](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/10/python-gnupg-gpg-example/) shows (which failes on my Ubuntu 20.04 / such a thing, but it's an old example; excerpt:

```
encrypted_data = gpg.encrypt(unencrypted_string, 'testgpguser@mydomain.com')
```

More-current (maybe?) references (like [this](https://gnupg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) and [this](https://github.com/isislovecruft/python-gnupg)) do not mention recipient email addresses, seemingly requiring numeric-only fingerprints for (presumably) public-key identication. Is it possible in today's environment (to identify a key solely by it's associated email_address/identity)? Possibly requiring a [keyserver](https://superuser.com/q/227991/98033)?

My tested [python-gnupg system versions](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/johnnyutahh/e32478cac863d5d2d7930cc94cd3a857/raw/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the version number in your question, you appear to be using the [pretty-bad-protocol](https://github.com/isislovecruft/python-gnupg) rewrite, which hasn't been updated since 2018.

If you simply install `python-gnupg`:

```
$ pip install python-gnupg
```

You get version `0.4.9`, which was released [just a few days ago](https://github.com/vsajip/python-gnupg/releases/tag/0.4.9):

```
Collecting python-gnupg
  Downloading http://.../python_gnupg-0.4.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Installing collected packages: python-gnupg
Successfully installed python-gnupg-0.4.9
```

Using this version of the `gnupg` module, your code works without a problem:

```
>>> import gnupg
>>> gpg = gnupg.G
gnupg.GPG(     gnupg.GenKey(
>>> gpg = gnupg.GPG()
>>> res = gpg.encrypt("this is a test", "bob@example.com")
>>> res.data
b'-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----\n...\n-----END PGP MESSAGE-----\n'
>>>
```

---

It is of course *better* to use a fingerprint, because you may have multiple keys in your keychain with the same email address, and you can't be certain which one you'll get. Using a fingerprint ensures that you get that specific key.

Comment: Thanks @larsks, this works well. Further, the `python-gnupg` module handles passphrase-based, private-key descryption much more elegantly (with a text/curses-based popup to request the passphrase from the calling user). There were some additional code-porting changes required (to interface with `python-gnupg` over `pretty_bad_protocol`), but all these required changes "made sense." Finally, the fingerprint-vs-email-address public-key identification point makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: Follow-on conversation where I pose the question of whether or not it's time to mark [pretty-bad-protocol](https://github.com/isislovecruft/python-gnupg) as obsolete: https://github.com/isislovecruft/python-gnupg/issues/285